# Spark Structured Streaming not writing data while reading from HDFS

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on a streaming script which should pickup files as soon as they land on HDFS, aggregate them and write them somewhere else.

Here, I cannot get the write to work - it creates the metadata folder, but no actual writing happens. Of 10+ files (all the same structure), only one was written and I am not sure why

Can anyone help me please?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, input_file_name, lower
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import sys
reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

now = datetime.now()

#create a contexit that supports hive
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session

### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('streaming_monitor')
    ssc = StreamingContext(spark_session, 1)
    print('start')
    print(datetime.now())

    myschema = StructType([
      StructField('text', StringType())
    ])

    #only files after stream starts
    df = spark_session\
        .readStream\
        .option('newFilesOnly', 'true')\
        .option('header', 'true')\
        .schema(myschema)\
        .text('hdfs://nameservice/user/user1/streamtest/')\
        .withColumn("FileName", input_file_name())

    output = df.createOrReplaceTempView('log')
    #hive_dump = spark_session.sql("select '" + str(now) + "' as timestamp, FileName, did_it_error, solution, text from log")

    output = df\
    .writeStream\
    .format("csv")\
    .queryName('logsmonitor')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///home/user1/analytics/logs/chkpoint_dir")\
    .start('hdfs://nameservice/user/user1/streamtest/output/')\
    .awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing here is that files read by Spark Streaming have to be placed into the source folder atomically. Otherwise, the file will be read as soon as it was created (and without having any content).
Spark will not act on updated data within a file but rather looks at a file exactly once.

You will see all your data floating if you

- stop your streaming job
- delete your checkpoint directory (or rename all input files to new and unique names)
- move all files into the source folder
- wait for the move to finish
- start streaming application

Of course, this will not be a solution if you want to let this job run continuously and adding more and more files, but the secret is really in placing the files *atomically* at once into the folder.

I am not completely familiar with HDFS but usually this atomicity can be achieved by writing the data into another folder and then moving it into the source folder.

Here is the reference in the documentation on [Input Sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources):

> "**File source** - Reads files written in a directory as a stream of data. Files will be processed in the order of file modification time. If latestFirst is set, order will be reversed. Supported file formats are text, CSV, JSON, ORC, Parquet. See the docs of the DataStreamReader interface for a more up-to-date list, and supported options for each file format. **Note that the files must be atomically placed in the given directory, which in most file systems, can be achieved by file move operations.**"

Comment: thanks for your answer! Sorry for a perhaps naive question,  what does it mean by "atomically" here? I noticed this problem in practice, when I debug in IntelliJ for example, I copy files using right click in IDE to the target directory, those files are NOT detected, while `cp` or `mv` from command line works.

Comment: Hi @benjamin, I am not an expert in file systems, but it is important that the file is created and populated within the same operation ("atomically"). If you use copy & past in IntelliJ, it will create an empty file and after that slowly copy the data over time until all data is in the file. Spark will look up the created but not populated file and never update it while the physical data is actually being copied into the file. The commands cp and mv mitigate this problem.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot.